# Bulid for loop based on given array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am generating dynamic textbox for save and add more functionality and i have to store that data in database i got the array but i dont know how to put that array in to loop so i can get my data.

Array looks like this based on this prepare loop so i can access every element of array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prem_type] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [phase_name] => a1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [counter] => 2
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [block] => A
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [block] => B
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prem_type] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [phase_name] => a2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [counter] => 2
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [block] => A
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [block] => B
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please write structure of expected array result as well

Comment: Maybe you can show your database query routine: it seems that your array structure can be simplified.

Comment: I am printing element like this but its giving me error that undefined index prem_type:                                                  for($i=0;$i<count($data1);$i++){
   for($j=0;$j<count($data1[$i]);$j++){
    for($k=0;$k<count($data1[$i][$j]);$k++){
     echo $data1[$i][$j][$k]['prem_type'];
    }
   }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data1);$i++){
            for($j=0;$j<count($data1[$i]);$j++){
                $prem_type =$data1[$i][$j][0]['prem_type'];
                $prem_name= $data1[$i][$j][1]['phase_name'];
                $no_of_phase= $data1[$i][$j][2]['counter'];
            echo $prem_type." ".$prem_name." ".$no_of_phase."<br>";
                    for($k=3;$k<count($data1[$i][$j]);$k++){
                            echo    $data1[$i][$j][$k]['unitname']."<br>";
                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to the data you can use something like:

```
foreach ($array AS $row) {
   $prem_type = $row[0][0]['prem_type'];
   $phase_name = $row[0][1]['phase_name'];
   $counter = $row[0][2]['counter'];
   $block1 = $row[0][3]['block'];
   $block2 = $row[0][4]['block'];
}
```

An alternative is to restructure the array into something more tidy:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array AS $rowId => $row) {
    $result[$rowId] = array(
        'prem_type' => $row[0][0]['prem_type'],
        'phase_name' => $row[0][1]['phase_name'],
        'counter' => $row[0][2]['counter'],
        'block1' => $row[0][3]['block'],
        'block2' => $row[0][4]['block']
    );
}
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [prem_type] => 1,
        [phase_name] => a1,
        [counter] => 2,
        [block1] => A,
        [block2] => B
    )
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$array = //your array

foreach($array as $value){
    foreach($value as $value2){
        foreach($value2 as $value3){
            foreach($value3 as $key3 => $value3){
                //$key3 is rem_type, phase_name…
                //$value3 is required values
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i access specific element using this loop because it is accessing all the element

Comment: you can use an if-else condition with the keys inside last foreach loop like: `if($key3 ==  "prem_type"){ //use value3 }`